# Kali linux Source lists fails

Tags: linux, apt, update, kali-linux

I am trying to update Kali Linux via the official `source_lists`
 while when i do `sudo apt-get update` it fails saying `W: Failed to fetch`
The source list is as follows :-

```
in /etc/apt/sources.list:
#regular repositories
deb http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free

#sources respositories
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
deb-src http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free
```

The output after installing some packages`apt-get update` is :-

```
W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/sana/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://security.kali.org/kali-security/dists/sana/updates/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'non-fre/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://security.kali.org/kali-security/dists/sana/updates/main/source/Sources  Unable to connect to security.kali.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://security.kali.org/kali-security/dists/sana/updates/contrib/source/Sources  Unable to connect to security.kali.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/sana/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to http.kali.org:http:

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Please post feedback if anything else is to be updated

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same thing today.  I was able to update one of our machines, earlier, but now it's mostly dead.

I know forums.kali.org is protected by Sucuri cloud proxy.  I can manually browse to most of http.kali.org, but occasionally get an error.  I wonder if the rest of the domain is also fronted by them.

As I type this, I'm watching a machine that just was able to get through apt-get update, but is timing out trying to fetch packages.

```
0% [Connecting to http.kali.org (192.99.200.113)]
```

Wish I could help more than confirm... it's not your machine.

Comment: tried now ,same thing hope it would get resolved soon

Comment: Yeah . it did update earlier .. while thanks for the confirmation again .. but need to find  any other way or source list ..

Comment: I tried it Today ..  and it worked ! .. i am happy though but suspicious of the situation at some time ..  Thanks for the help ..